# Angular 4 reusing mock for components unit testing

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, mocking

I'm writing a test for all of our components. I was wondering how can I reuse the common mock service so I will not be declaring it every time on each component's unit test.

```
class MockNavigateService {
  page: Page;
  constructor() {
    this.page= new Page();
  }
  navigateNext() {}
}

class TestQuestionsProvider extends QuestionService {
  getQuestions(key: string): QuestionBase<any>[] {
    return [];
  }

}

class MockModelService {
  createModel(): any {
    return {};
  }

  getModel(): any {
    return {};
  }

}
```

**UPDATE:** How do I move these services to a separate file and import it to my unit test so that I will not be declaring it anymore

Comment: this class can be injected when you are testing. **what is the issue you are getting?**

Comment: If I understood your question correctly: you can move it to a separate file and import like you would normally do with any other services

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to move MockNavigateService , MockModelService and TestQuestionsProvider  to a separate file. How do I import it and assign those services to my testBed.configureTestingModule as providers

Comment: @stuckoverflow24 I'm also looking for this solution, Did you achieved any solution? Please post your answer if you did.